# trying to solve a quadratic equation with surdic term.

Tags: quadratics, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, quartics

I am trying to come up with a solution for this quadratic equation, I've not gotten any meaningful solutions. Please help:

$$y^2–11\sqrt{y}+24 = 0$$

Comment: I think that's a quartic equation.

Comment: Try graphing it.

Comment: The word "linear" means the variable is to the first power. A term like $-11\sqrt{y}$ is by no means linear.

Answer (score 1):

substituting $$\sqrt{y}=t$$ then you have to solve
$$t^4-11t+24=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo. The equation should be y^2-11y+24 = 0.
you can then find the prime factors of 24 to come up with 8 and 3 as the roots of the equation.

Comment: The point is that he is clear: "quadratic equation with surdic term".

Comment: sure and he can't be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM
$$y^2-11\sqrt{y}+24=y^2+8+8+8-11\sqrt{y}\geq4\sqrt[4]{8^3y^2}-11\sqrt{y}=\left(4\sqrt[4]{512}-11\right)\sqrt{y}>0,$$
which says that our equation has no real roots.

If you mean to solve $$y-11\sqrt{y}+24=0$$ then it's
$$(\sqrt{y}-3)(\sqrt{y}-8)=0,$$ which gives
$$y\in\{9,64\}.$$